# How to publish a model as a service?

Tags: modelbuilder, geoprocessing-service

I am trying to share a map as a service and overwrite an existing Feature Service in ArcGIS Online. I put together a small model to connect to the database, to publish and replace existing item online, but I am not seeing the "Share As a Service" tool in the ArcToolbox. 
How can I share it as a service with ModelBuilder?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do users need to be able to use/edit the service in AGOL? If they just need to access it and download for local use, you can use the Share Package tool in Model Builder. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

You won't see any option to share as a service from the toolbox itself. In 10.1 the change was made to publish *results*, which is the information about successfully running a tool. (That can be a system tool, a python script tool or a model tool). Your entry point for creating a geoprocessing service is the **Results Window**.

See the [Quick Tour](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/a-quick-tour-of-publishing-a-geoprocessing-service.htm) for more information.